# Can't lower Radio Button Width

Tags: xaml, radio-button, windows-phone-8.1

I have a windows phone project and I can't resize the radio button width. Which is pushing my `textblock` off screen.
Here is my Xaml code:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="spRadioSelection" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,100" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBlock Text="Staging" FontSize="24" Margin="30,20"></TextBlock>

            <RadioButton x:Name="rbStaging" GroupName="ProductionLevel" IsChecked="true" Checked="SelectionChangedHandler" Width="68"/>
            <RadioButton x:Name="rbLive" GroupName="ProductionLevel" IsChecked="false" Checked="SelectionChangedHandler"></RadioButton>
            <TextBlock Text="Live" FontSize="32" Margin="30,20"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can change the `MinWidth` rather than `Width`

```
 <RadioButton x:Name="rbStaging" GroupName="ProductionLevel"  
                 IsChecked="true" Checked="SelectionChangedHandler" MinWidth="68" />
```

Probably need to reduce the Margins on the TextBlock as well. Hope that helps